# path of temporary file

Tags: mysql, temporary-files, tmp

When I alter or repair a myisam table, it creates a temporary file in the same directory as of data directory.
How do I make it use /tmp directory?

I do not have enough space on the partition where the data directory is located.

Update:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html

The last line of this page reads:
ALTER TABLE creates a temporary table in the same directory as the original table.

Repair table has an option but it does not work.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisamchk-repair-options.html#option_myisamchk_tmpdir

This seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually mysql uses the `TMPDIR` environment variable or a system default.

See also the documentaion on [temporary-files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-files.html)

Comment: While using "alter table" I noticed that it is using the same directory instead of tmpdir path.

Comment: As per the documentation link provided by you ... "ALTER TABLE creates a temporary table in the same directory as the original table" Is it possible to change the location of the tmp file being used by alter table?